# How do I apply styling to my custom intro page?

Tags: css, eclipse-rcp

I made my own welcome intro page using org.eclipse.ui.intro and I'm able to show my welcome extended with other contributors.

Now I'd like to decore my welcome with some css, and I have two question:

1) How can I apply predefined eclipse css (i.e Slate) to my page? I've already tried putting org.eclipse.ui.intro/INTRO_THEME = org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal.slate in plugin_customizazion.ini without success

2) there's a way to extend css to contributors without giving them the css file??? I mean there a way for contributors to use my own css if it is only inside my plugin (or eclipse plugin if i will be able to use "slate" style?)

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse SDK Help](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_intro_ext_theme.htm)

> The only way to select a theme is via the preference org.eclipse.ui.intro/INTRO_THEME in plugin_customization.ini.
>
> Theme-enabled intro implementation must make all the references to style and presentation resources using the $theme$ substitution variable. Absolute paths for images, pages, styles, etc. will be computed by resolving the substitution variable using the path of the currently active theme.

See [Intro Content XML Format](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/introContentFileSpec.html) as well.

To answer the second question, if you define an intro theme which include your css file, other plugins will be able to use it for sure.

Cheers,
Max

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I've learned more about themes, but I think I have some problem with path.
I've defined my own theme, css and graphics, so I extend theme by configExtension. But when I load my application the welcome page doesn't load css neither images. I've also defined org.eclipse.ui.intro/INTRO_THEME in plugin_customization.ini.

I have a structure similar to slate template like this

```
my.plugin.name
|_resources
  |_intro
    |_graphics
    |_html
```

in graphics there are all images definitions whlile in html there are css
then in intro I have my root.xhtml (referenced by intro.xml)
with this css reference

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="$themes$/html/root-ie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
```

finally I've defined configExtension with theme

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.intro.configExtension">
  <theme
        default="true"
        id="my.plugin.name.themes.themename"
        name="%theme.name.themenam"
        path="/resources/intro"
        scalable="true">
```

I think maybe the problem is with the path, I've also tried with path="resources/intro"
path="/resources/intro/" and path="resources/intro/" withous success

could someone post a simple but complete working sample please?